# admin/commerce/orders/{orderId}/payments/add "You are not authorized to access this page."

Tags: 8, commerce

When I try to add a new payment to an order (either created by a customer or via the backend) I always encounter the "You are not authorized to access this page." error.

My user has the administrator role.

I'm running core 8.6.7 and commerce 2.11.0

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, I needed to add one payment method that is not "Offsite"

the error message is just very misleading.

Comment: Indeed; instead of a 403 it should just be a 404 and not show the link. Can you open a task for this in the issue queue?